# Possible bug in reputation summary in user homepage

Tags: support, bug, reputation, reputation-history

In my homepage, I see my recent reputation history as

[image]

whereas, actually it should have shown +2, [4 Downvote / 1 upvote]

[image]

There is no score against the latest answer.Is it a bug ?

I'm on Chrome Version 41.0.2272.101 m, on Windows 8.1, if that matters.

Comment: No repro here on Win Chrome.

Comment: @bluefeet I am seeing the same even in two different tabs in my browser. Do you need a complete window screenshot? Will that help?

Comment: @bluefeet I got the same in Mozilla Firefox, too. :-(

Comment: What I can see at this answer it has actually +8/-8. So the blank might be intentional for your view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in fact not a bug but a funny circumstance:

You received 4 downvotes and 1 upvote. Since you reached the 200 reputation cap today, you cannot get a +10 from that answer but just +8 to ballance from the downvotes.

> [image]

If you receive more upvotes there you will see:

```
   XX ago   upvote

^
nothing, no +10
```

Comment: Ok, so this is a _status-by-design_ thing? I was expecting a 0, atleast, not a blank space though. Sorry for the confusion. Thank you sir. :-)